# xml sorting via xslt

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, transpose

i need some help with sorting xmlelements based on another xml.  my main xml is as below

```
<xml>
<A1>value</A1>
<A2>value</A2>
<B1>value</B1>
<B2>value</B2>
</xml>
```

i want another xml which looks liks this

```
<xml>
<A1>value</A1>
<B1>value</B1>
<A2>value</A2>
<B2>value</B2>
</xml>
```

sortign is not based on any key or any value. the ordering is determined on the fly(by reading the order from DB) and the main xml has to be transposed to that order.  from db values are like

```
tagname | order
------------
A1 | 1
B1 | 2
A2 | 3
A3 | 4
```

how do i do this? i can form the xslt dynamically. but what should that xslt be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If the sort order is "not based on any key or any value" then what is it based on? XSLT can read from the source XML or from other documents you point it at (in XSLT 1.0, these too would be have to be XML documents). It cannot "read from DB".

Comment: it is not based on any key.  we have predefined list of elements and the ordering of elements are determined dynamically.  so it is better that order information comes from DB.  i can read db values and form a xslt by writing a c# program.

Comment: Do you mean you create the XSLT itself "on-the-fly"? If yes, can you insert this table into in the form of XML - for example: `<elem name="A1" order="1"/>`?

Answer (score 1):

How about ...

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:variable name="elem-order" as="element(elem)*">
  <elem name="A1" />
  <elem name="B1" />
  <elem name="A2" />
  <elem name="B2" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="index-of( $elem-order, $elem-order[@name eq local-name( current())])" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

If the element order is to come from an external file, redefine the $elem-order variable like so ...

```
<xsl:variable
    name="elem-order"
    select="doc('what-ever-uri')/elements/elem" />
```

... or pass it in as a stylesheet parameter.

Comment: can you give me the main xml that will work with this xsl? when i try my main example, it is giving error

Comment: I don't understand. What is a main xml? And what was the error message?

Comment: Thanks Sean.  How should this xml be? <xml>
<A1>value</A1>
<A2>value</A2>
<B1>value</B1>
<B2>value</B2>
</xml>